# Иероглифы при создании строки из набора байт

Tags: java

Делаю шифрование строки через xor. Строка в формате UTF-8 на русском языке. После операций не могу восстановить строку в нормальный вид.

```
    String text = "Какой-нибудь русский текст";
    String sKey = LFSR(); // return string "10011010" for example

    System.out.println("[PSP]: key: " + sKey); // output: 10011010

    byte[] txt = text.getBytes();
    byte[] key = sKey.getBytes();

    byte[] res = new byte[txt.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; ++i) {
        res[i] = (byte) (txt[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
    }

    try {
        System.out.println(new String(res, "UTF-8")); 
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
 ފ���������������������������������������
```

P.S. В IDE везде кодировка UTF-8

Comment: Непонятно чего вы ожидаете пытаясь интерпретировать случайный набор байт как утф8

Comment: @AlexeyTen, но у меня строка text в UTF-8 формате тоже, здесь я для примера вывел так. На самом деле текст читается с файла, который в кодировке UTF-8. Мне в консоль не принципиально выводить строку, пытался в файл вывести - безрезультатно тоже.

Comment: Вы взяли текст в utf8. Взяли из него байты. ПоXORили его с какими-то байтами. И ожидаете что полученный набор байт можно читать как utf8? А самое главное, зачем вам вообще читать res в виде строки?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, вообще строка sKey по идее тоже в UTF-8. Это метод шифрования, я хочу зашифровать исходную строку text с помощью ключа sKey, используя XOR. В конце вывод соответственно

Comment: Повторю в третий раз: результат XORа вовсе не обязан быть валидным utf8 (и скорее всего и не будет).

Comment: @AlexeyTen, понял. даже не знаю как поступить тогда, преподаватель принципиально просит зашифровать русский текст с помощью XOR)

Comment: @VitaljaB. расшифруйте строку обратно прежде чем паристь в UTF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String text = "Какой-нибудь русский текст"//ваш код будет работать если тут будет уже >Ранее Зашифрованный< текст
    String sKey = "10011010"; // return string "10011010" for example
    System.out.println("[PSP]: key: " + sKey); // output: 10011010

    byte[] txt = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] key = sKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] res = new byte[txt.length];

    // Шифруем текст
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; ++i) {
        res[i] = (byte) (txt[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
    }

    System.out.println("Зашифрованный текст:" + new String(res, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    // Расшифровка текста
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; ++i) {
        res[i] = (byte) (res[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
    }

    System.out.println("Расшифрованный текст:" + new String(res, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Как-то так на выходе:
Зашифрованный текст:������������������������������
Расшифрованный текст:Какой-нибудь русский текст

Я так понял, что не получится получить в зашифрованном тексте корректную кириллицу?

Comment: @VitaljaB. вы зашифровали текст! в этом весь и смысл шифрования что без расшифровки вы не можете прочитать  правильный текст в кириллице для декодера UTF-8 ваш текст просто набор байт по этому он и выводит его в знаках � если хочешь можем открыть чат я постараюсь объяснить лучше

Comment: К примеру вы шифруете букву А ей соответствует бинарный код (11010000 10010000) можно посмотреть тут https://unicode-table.com/en/0410/ затем вы шифруете её при помощи XOR
и ваша  А  превращается в (11100001 10100000) что соответствует этим символам по Unicod'у https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=E1A0 в вашей ide эти символы могут отображаться как �

Comment: @Miepolz320, откройте чат, есть пара вопросов

Comment: @Miepolz320, кстати, а почему если мы используем не кириллицу, а строку на английском языке, то после шифрования строка содержит в себе английские символы без иероглифов ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105953/discussion-between-minepolz320-and-vitalja-b).